# How do I switch back to viewing decompiled code in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

When using the debugger I would like to switch from viewing what IntelliJ thinks is the source code and view the decompiled code. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you attach sources to a library? Try removing them.

Comment: I want to view decompiled source for a file that is a source file. For example, I compile and deploy the project code and make changes to the source. In the debugger it wont match up so I want to view the decompiled code.